# Как вывести данные из массива в обратном порядке

Tags: xcode, swift

Допустим у меня есть массив `var code = [25, 17, 46, 23, 55]` и мне надо вывести из него данные.
Можно это сделать с помощью 
`for var i = code.count; i<0; i-=1 {print ("\(code[i])")}` но xcode пишет, что стиль c++ скоро будет удален и даже не выводит мне результат. 
Есть ли у меня в коде ошибка, и если нет, то каким еще способом можно вывести данные в обратном порядке?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В вашем примере кода две ошибки:

```
for var i = code.count-1; i>=0; i-=1 {print ("\(code[i])")}
```

Переписать его можно следующим образом:

```
for i in (0...code.count-1).reverse() {
    print ("\(code[i])")
}
```

Comment: У Наташи, кстати, есть отличная статья на эту тему https://www.natashatherobot.com/swift-alternatives-to-c-style-for-loops/

Answer (score 0):

```
var massive = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
    
func revers(mass: [Int]) -> [Int] {
    var bufer = [Int]()

    for value in massive.reversed() {
       bufer += [value]
    }
    
    return bufer
}

var bufer = revers(mass: massive)
print(bufer)
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]